Can't put values together into struct that is initiated by pointer and malloc
Just a simple struct called person, inside I need to store name and age. I'm trying to dynamically allocate memory for my struct.
Without using pointer:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
} person;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    person a = {"bob", 15};    // Here, we can input values "together", all at once
    printf("name is %s, age is %i\n", a.name, a.age);

    return 0;
}

Here, it can successfully print out:
name is bob, age is 15
Using pointer:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    person *a = (person *) malloc(sizeof(person));
    if (a == NULL)
        return 1;

    *a = {"bob", 15};    // Here I tried to input the all values
    printf("name is %s, age is %i\n", a->name, a->age);
    
    free(a);

    return 0;
}

It won't compile and return the error:
expected expression before '{' token
Well, if I try to input the value one by one:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    person *a = (person *) malloc(sizeof(person));
    if (a == NULL)
        return 1;
    a->name = "bob";
    a->age = 15;
    printf("name is %s, age is %i\n", a->name, a->age);

    free(a);

    return 0;
}

it can successfully print out:
name is bob, age is 15
I expected that since the pointer is pointing to memory allocated to be a struct person, values can be input together just like a normal struct. But as you can see, it couldn't. However, when values were input one by one, it worked.
Did I do sth wrong? Or when using pointers, I need to input the value one by one? Thank you.

You likely want a compound literal.
And don't cast the return from malloc.
int main(void)
{
    person *a = malloc(sizeof(person));
    *a = (person){"bob", 15};    // Here I tried to input the all values
    printf("name is %s, age is %i\n", a->name, a->age);

    free(a);

    return 0;
}

You also should get in the habit of checking to ensure that malloc succeeded before using that memory.

My bad for not checking NULL for malloc, will do. in C++ was told to cast, but now I know why I shouldn't cast mallocs. Thank you!

No time like the present to learn that C != C++. The fact that you can often compile C code with a C++ compiler is a common trap.
